# Targeting <li> containing <ul> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a menu where i need to use jQuery to target parent elements, but I can't get the jQuery `:has` selector to work.

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
$('nav > div > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass('parent');
$('nav > div > ul > li:has(ul)').click(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

[My fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/CTa27/1)

Comment: Always remember to put the code as part of your question, not just into a jsFiddle.

Comment: Your `li`s don't contain any `ul`, they are outside of them - which is invalid HTML.

Comment: Even the simplest case of `'li:has(ul)'` does not work as your ULs are not actually inside your LIs :)

Comment: change your html http://jsfiddle.net/CTa27/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the simplest case of 'li:has(ul)' does not work as your ULs are not actually inside your LIs. Fix your HTML as follows:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/CTa27/2/

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link
                <ul>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link
                <ul>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your submenu `<ul>` inside of `<li>`
Find the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sYLdd/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('nav li').addClass('no-parent');
    jQuery('nav li:has(ul)').removeClass('no-parent').addClass('parent');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you want to use jQuery to target the ul, Maybe you can just add your class to the ul.

```
<ul class="parent"></ul>
```

Comment: Their problem is simply invalid HTML (the ULs are not nested inside the LIs). :)